# Downloading file from Google Drive and sending the file as HttpResponse to client-side via Google Drive python client

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api

I have Django 1.10 project in which I have a module for working with Google Drive data. 
Currently my goal is to download a file from Google Drive to the local PC of the user. As of now, I have the following code:

```
def a_files_google_download(request):
   #...
   service = build("drive", "v2", http=http)
   download_url = file.get('downloadUrl')
   resp, content = service._http.request(download_url)
   fo = open("foo.exe", "wb")
   fo.write(content)
```

I am stuck at this point and don't know how to pass the `fo` as HttpResponse.
Clearly, I don't know the file type in advance. It can be .mp3, .exe, .pdf...And the code should work irrespective of the file type.
Also, I don't want to send the file as a zip-file.
Is it possible ? Help me please with this !

Answer (score 1):

Check out Wesley Chun's python tutorial using python to download and upload drive files using Python in [Google Drive API: Uploading & Downloading Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7YH6rdR-tk) where he demoes this both in v2 and v3.

There's additional explanation and source code in his official blog in [Google Drive: Uploading & Downloading files with Python](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os

from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

FILES = (
    ('hello.txt', False),
    ('hello.txt', True),
)

for filename, convert in FILES:
    metadata = {'title': filename}
    res = DRIVE.files().insert(convert=convert, body=metadata,
            media_body=filename, fields='mimeType,exportLinks').execute()
    if res:
        print('Uploaded "%s" (%s)' % (filename, res['mimeType']))

if res:
    MIMETYPE = 'application/pdf'
    res, data = DRIVE._http.request(res['exportLinks'][MIMETYPE])
    if data:
        fn = '%s.pdf' % os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        with open(fn, 'wb') as fh:
            fh.write(data)
        print('Downloaded "%s" (%s)' % (fn, MIMETYPE))
```